Compute the integral: $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2+\sqrt{x+1}}{(1+x)^2-\sqrt{x-1}}dx$
The integral is from my MIT Integration Bee 2025 Mock Training Problems. But unfortunately, I forgot the solutions nor the trick to this problem.
I tried letting $u=\sqrt{x-1}$, then perform trig-substitution on $u=\sqrt{2}\sec\theta$.
However, this resulted to a nasty rational trig-function.
I tried letting $u=\sqrt{x+1}$, but then $u=\sqrt{2}\tan\theta$ results the same nasty rational trig-function.
I thought about maybe finding a sneaky way to conjugate the denominator, but that square is out of the way.
Any sneaky way to solve this integral?

My first thought was this might be one of those problems where you divide the fraction by a common factor and the numerator is a derivative of the denominator. But the good(?) news is wolfram doesn't believe this has an antiderivative in terms of its standard list of functions so maybe we don't have to bash our heads in figuring out that integrating factor. I also tried the substitution $x-1=2\sinh^2t$ but it didn't get me anywhere.

Using only Mathematica: $$\frac{\pi  , _3F_2\left(\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{27}{2048}\right)}{32 \sqrt{2}}+,
_4F_3\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},1,1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{27}{2048}\right)+\sqrt{2} ,
_5F_4\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{6},1,1;\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8},\frac{9}{8};\frac{27}{2048}\right)+\frac{1}{15} ,
_5F_4\left(\frac{2}{3},1,1,\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2};\frac{7}{8},\frac{9}{8},\frac{11}{8},\frac{13}{8};\frac{27}{2048}\right)$$

Yea, I'm pretty sure I made a mistake making this integral, I remember the intentional solution was supposed to be like 7ln(3)/3. But I think I miswrote it.

By $x\leftarrow\tfrac{t^2}{4}+\tfrac{1}{t^2}$, the integral equals $4\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\infty}\frac{((t+2)^2-2)(t^2+2)(t^2-2)}{(t^2+2)^4-(2t)^3(t^2-2)}\mathrm{d}t$, so it must be expressible as a sum of logarithms and arctangents of real algebraic numbers. But the denominator is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so the expression cannot be "nice".

The integral in your self answer has no simple closed form but here's this:
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+2}{(x+1)^2-\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$
Substitute $\sqrt{1+x}=u$,
$$I=2\int\frac{u+2}{u^3-1} \,du$$
Using $u^3-1=(u-1)(u^2+u+1)$,
$$I=2\int\frac{u+2}{(u-1)(u^2+u+1)} \,du=2\int \frac{1}{u-1}\,du-2\int \frac{u+1}{u^2+u+1}\,du$$
$$=2\int \frac{1}{u-1}\,du -\int \frac{2u+1}{u^2+u+1}\,du-\int\frac{1}{u^2+u+1}\,du$$
Now evaluating these integrals is straightforward:
$$(1) \int \frac1x \,dx= \ln|x|$$
$$(2)\int\frac{f'(x)}{{f(x)}}\,dx=\ln(f(x))$$
$$(3)\int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}=\frac1a\arctan \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$
and all this will match your old notes from the journal
$$I=2\ln|\sqrt{x+1}-1|-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\ln|4x+4\sqrt{x+1}+8|+C$$
$$I=2\ln|\sqrt{x+1}-1|-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\ln|x+\sqrt{x+1}+2|+C$$
And,
$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x+1}+2}{(x+1)^2-\sqrt{x+1}}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt3}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{3+\sqrt2}{3-2\sqrt2}\right)-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}$$

OHHHHHHH, got it, so it was originally a typo then. Thank you so much!!!

Not an entirely satisfying answer, but at least I can show how to get an exponentially convergent series representation that evaluates to the hypergeometric result in the comment by @Mariusz Iwaniuk.
With $x=1+2\tan(x)^2$, the integral becomes
$$I=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{2\cos(x) + \sqrt{2}}{4 - \sqrt{2} \sin(x) \cos(x)^3} \sin(x)\,\text{d}x.$$
Expanding in a geometric series gives
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \bigl(2\cos(x) + \sqrt{2}\bigr) \sin(x) \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \sin(x) \cos(x)^3\right)^n\,\text{d}x.$$
With the Beta function $B(x,y) = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(t)^{2x-1} \cos(t)^{2y-1}\,\text{d}t$ we get
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^n \left\{ B\left(1+\frac{n}{2}, 1 + \frac{3n}{2}\right) + B\left(1+\frac{n}{2}, \frac{1+3n}{2}\right) \right\}.$$
With $B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ this evaluates to
$$I = \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{-3n/2} \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{n}{2}\right) \left\{ \frac{\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{3n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(2 + 2n\right)} + \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+3n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2} + 2n\right)} \right\}.$$
Using WolframAlpha, the even $n$ sum up to
$${}_4F_3\left( \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1, 1; \frac{2}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{4}; \frac{27}{2048} \right) + \sqrt{2} {}_5F_4\left( \frac{1}{6}, \frac{3}{6}, \frac{5}{6}, 1, 1; \frac{3}{8}, \frac{5}{8}, \frac{7}{8}, \frac{9}{8}; \frac{27}{2048} \right)$$
and the odd $n$ sum to
$$\frac{1}{15} {}_5F_4\left( \frac{2}{3}, 1, 1, \frac{4}{3}, \frac{3}{2}; \frac{7}{8}, \frac{9}{8}, \frac{11}{8}, \frac{13}{8}; \frac{27}{2048} \right) + \frac{\pi}{32\sqrt{2}} {}_3F_2\left( \frac{5}{6}, \frac{7}{6}, \frac{9}{6}; \frac{5}{4}, \frac{7}{4}; \frac{27}{2048} \right).$$

Oh god, I'm starting to think there must be a mistake in my integral then or a typo that I can't find. Thank you for this!

OMG I FOUND THE INDEFINITE ANSWER FROM MY OLD INT BEE JOURNAL!!!!
So apparently, the indefinite solution I wrote down 6-7 years ago was
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+2}{(x+1)^2-\sqrt{x-1}}dx$$
$$=2\ln|\sqrt{x+1}-1|-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x+1}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\ln|4x+4\sqrt{x+1}+8|+C$$
So now the problem is, how do I find this solution by hand???

This answer should be an addendum to the original question, or perhaps a new question; it describes the answer as found in a book, but still asks how the original question should be solved, and is thus not really an answer per the standards of this site.

$x-1$ must bee $x+1$  and this is result not answer.

Oh. Not even the result. The result is an absurd number.
